# Building Vue for development and runtime only for use in Chrome Apps

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, google-chrome-app

I am struggling with converting a jQuery based Chrome app to Vue. Because of Chrome Apps' `Content Security Policy (CSP)` it is not possible to use `eval()` and thus compiling templates must be done beforehand.

That itself is not a problem with Vue's `Single File Components (SFC)` approach where all templates get compiled to render functions in the build process.

However, since the build target is *production* all warnings and helpful comments from Vue are stripped off. So for example, if I forget a property for a component, I get not warning about it. It just won't show up. That makes development very difficult.

Then, if I in `package.json` for `build` use:

```
"build": "vue-cli-service build --mode development"
```

I get an error in the Chrome app:

`Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource: 'wasm-eval'".`

And there are indeed a lot of `eval`s in the index.js file starting with

```
eval("__webpack_require_
```

So my question is:

How do I make the build system preserve warnings and hints in the console without using the forbidden `eval`'s?

I am not sure if the problem is caused by the template compiler being included, but if so, how do I tell the builder not to use the compiler but still use development mode?

Comment: Does this help? https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/08/vue-js-chrome-extension/

Comment: This is for extensions, you can easily make one for chrome apps:  https://github.com/Kocal/vue-web-extension

Comment: @Alireza: Thanks, but as soon as I choose development mode it starts using eval() and then it doesn't work anymore. My goal is to have it use runtime only but still development mode.

Comment: Does it work when you build?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. I just miss the debug info from Vue in dev mode. Plus, I would like the JS to be non-minified.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77557516/8583692

Answer (score 1):

It is an "issue" with the CSP, you need to use the vue.runtime.js version of Vue.

Please refer to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make Vue use the runtime version instead when building the project?